# Std error of measurement and CIs for inter-rater observations

Tags: confidence-interval, reliability, measurement-error, agreement-statistics

Reliability is often reported somewhat abstractly and can be difficult to interpret (e.g., ICC = 0.9). For test-retest reliability, it can be helpful to express measurement error in the scale of the instrument, i.e., as the standard error of measurement (SEM = standard deviation × sqrt(1-ICC). From this, confidence intervals (CI = 1.96 × SEM) can be calculated for the observed values*. Interpreting the reliability of an instrument as the width of the CI can be more intuitive than the ICC value.

**My question is: As inter-rater reliability can similarly be estimated via ICC, is it also reasonable to express inter-rater reliability as SEM and from this to calculate CIs around individual observed data points?**

Thank you!

(*) I know from Weir 2005 and Charter 1996 etc that this CI is not strictly correct as it is calculated based on the observed value rather than the estimated true value - but never mind that now - my question still stands.

Comment: Please post the full citations of Weir 2005 and Charter 1996. Thanks!

Comment: Charter, R. A. (1996). Revisiting the standard errors of measurement, estimate, and prediction and their application to test scores. Perceptual and Motor Skills, 82(3), 1139–1144. https://doi.org/10.2466/pms.1996.82.3c.1139
Weir, J. P. (2005). Quantifying test-retest reliability using the intraclass correlation coefficient and the SEM. Journal of Strength and Conditioning Research, 19(1), 231–240. https://doi.org/10.1519/15184.1